# Executing Methods with ItemTemplate Parameters in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, eval

I need to execute a method within an `ItemTemplate` in my `DataList`. How do I format the method in the page to work correctly with an `Eval`?

The method takes an `int` as a parameter.

```
<%# NumberOfEmplyeeOrders(Int32.Parse("EmployeeID"))%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a syntax error in my cast. Here is the correct code:

```
<%#NumberOfEmplyeeOrders((Int32)(Eval("EmployeeID"))) %>
```

Answer (score 7):

`<%# NumberOfEmplyeeOrders((Int32)Eval("EmployeeID")) %>`